# If a block upper triangular matrix is diagonizable, then are some of its blocks diagonizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose $n>1$ and $X, Y, Z \in M_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$. Let $A = \left(\begin{matrix}X & Y\\0_n & Z\end{matrix}\right)$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then are $X$ and $Z$ also diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable then its minimal polynomial $m_A$ has roots of algebraic multiplicity $1$.

Now powers of $A$ are upper-triangular with powers of $Z$ and $Z$ on the diagonal:
$$
\pmatrix{X&Y\\0&Z}\pmatrix{X&Y\\0&Z} = \pmatrix{X^2&*\\0&Z^2}.
$$
Per induction you can show that for every polynomial $p$ it holds
$$
p(A) = \pmatrix{p(X)&*\\0&p(Z)}.
$$
It follows that $m_A(X)=0$ and $m_A(Z)=0$. This implies diagonalizability of $X$ and $Y$ by the properties of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'd like to ask how is it that X and Z satisfy the minimal polynomial of A.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The minimal polynomial of $ I $ is $ x - 1 $, and it certainly has one root, $ 1 $, of algebraic multiplicity $ 1 $.

Comment: Alright, this just blew my mind. I never thought of using that property to show that X and Z satisfy the minpoly of A. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad.